# `Select2` Alternate other input placeholder on val change

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a seclet2 dropdown with two options

```
<select id="ddlsearch">
  <option value="0">Translated Search</option>
  <option value="1" selected="">Exact Search</option>
</select>
```

It seems to change the placeholder correctly for the first `if` statement but I cant seem to get my else statement working. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
function selectPlaceholder() {
    var reportLevel = "0",
        $select = $("#ddlsearch")

    if (reportLevel == "0") {
        $select.on("change", function(e) {
            $('#txtkey').attr('placeholder', 'asd')
        });
    } else {
        $select.on("change", function(e) {
            $('#txtkey').attr('placeholder', '123')
        });
    }
};
selectPlaceholder()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this...

```js
$("#ddlsearch").on("change", function(e) {
  if ("0" == this.value) {
    $('#txtkey').attr('placeholder', 'asd')
  } else {
    $('#txtkey').attr('placeholder', 'fgh')
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4> Your select </h4>

<select id="ddlsearch">
  <option value="0">Translated Search</option>
  <option value="1" selected="">Exact Search</option>
</select>

<h4> Your text input somewhere </h4>
<input id='txtkey'>
```

The `if` statement should reside inside the `change` event handler, and placeholder should be changed based on value of the select.

Comment: Instead of using `this.value` you can also use `$(this).val()` both will give the same results ;-)

Comment: Derp, I could of swore i tried that it was the ending .change that got me i think. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Kindly accept the answer when you are happy with it :-)